# extends user FOSUserBundle Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have the the follow problem when I try extends the User

In FormType:

```
class RegistrationFormType extends BaseType{

public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

    // add your custom field
    $builder->add('telephone')
            ->add('adress')
            ->add('CPF');

}

public function getName()
{
    return 'project_user_registration';
}
```

}

and I have:

```
* @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
* @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
* @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"user" = "User", "individual" = "Individual"})
class User extends BaseUser{
 /**
 * @var string $adress
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="adress", type="string", length=255)
 */
 private $adress;

 /**
 * @var string $telephone
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="telephone", type="string", length=20)
 */
 private $telephone;

 //getters and setters...

}

* @ORM\Table()
* @ORM\Entity
class Individual extends User{

   /**
    * @var string $CPF
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="CPF", type="string", length=14)
    */
    private $CPF;


    public function setCPF($cPF)
    {
       $this->CPF = $cPF;
    }


    public function getCPF()
    {
       return $this->CPF;
    }
}
```

When I do this, i've got an error :

> Neither property "CPF" nor method "getCPF()" nor method "isCPF()" exists in class "Project\UserBundle\Entity\User"

somebody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You've probably configured the FOSUserBundle to use your `User` entity, and it doesn't know about `Individual`. Is there a reason you need to extend `User` again, or can you just add the property and methods to that class?

Otherwise, you can configure FOS to use `Individual` as the user model class, and it won't throw that error.

Comment: I realy need to extend User again.